# Regenerate EntityModel which is DataContract

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, entity-model

I have a Data Model generated by Entity Framework using DataBase First approach. This dataModel is located in a WCF Service and is returned by multiple methods to the client. In the client application, the type `CreationType` is declared in the service reference ( by updating the service reference ).

```
// This code was generated from a template.
[DataContract]
public partial class CreationType
{
    public CreationType()
    {
        this.Quotes = new HashSet<Quote>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int CreationTypeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string NameFr { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string NameEn { get; set; }
}
```

The question is: Is there a way to regenerate the model without loosing WCF attributes? I mean, can they be declared in a non-generated file and be apply to the generated like in a partial class or something?

I don't necessary need all properties being DataMember and I don't want every EntityModel being DataContract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can edit template from which EF classes are generated. By editing T4 template you can control behavior of EF class generator.

You are looking for file `*.tt` or to be more specific: `YourModelName.tt`

Inside this file you can find a rules along with EF classes are generated.

Here are lines that should be changed:

```
[DataContract]
<#=Accessibility.ForType(entity)#> <#=code.SpaceAfter(code.AbstractOption(entity))#>partial class <#=code.Escape(entity)#><#=code.StringBefore(" : ", code.Escape(entity.BaseType))#>
```

Next line is:

```
[DataMember]
<#=PropertyVirtualModifier(Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty))#> <#=code.Escape(edmProperty.TypeUsage)#> <#=code.Escape(edmProperty)#>
```

You probably gonna need to add also this line:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization" #>
```

in this section:

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
```

Comment: I could do that, but by using this method every models will be data contracts. I just need some of them and I don't necessary need all properties being DataMember.